# Getting points inside buffer in leaflet

Tags: php, ajax, leaflet, turfjs

I am trying to get the nearest farmers (points) to a specific customer (point). I made a buffer to this customer and then used turf-inside to get the points inside the buffer, but it doesn't work and I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: A coordinate, feature, or point geometry is required

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"CustomerID_geojson.php",
        data:{'Cust_Name': Cust_Name} ,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var unit = 'kilometers'
            var buffered = turf.buffer(response, distance, unit)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'allfarmers_geojson.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var ptsWithin = turf.inside(data, buffered);
                    geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(ptsWithin).addTo(mymap);
                    mymap.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
                }
             })
            }
        })
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which line did produce this error?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, the error in this line "var ptsWithin = turf.inside(data, buffered);"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`turf.inside`](https://turfjs.org/docs/#inside) docs and signature:

> Takes a **Point** and a Polygon or MultiPolygon and determines if the point resides inside the polygon.
>
> Parameters
>
> **point** (`Feature<Point>)` input point
>
> polygon (`Feature<(Polygon | MultiPolygon)>)` input polygon or multipolygon

You might rather be interested in [`turf.within`](https://turfjs.org/docs/#within) instead.

---

Original answer:

That error message complains that either your `response` or `data` is not a valid argument for `turf.buffer` or `turf.inside` respectively. Please output the content of those variables and make sure they comply with what Turf expects.

Comment: the first part of the buffer is working fine,and i tried to output the result for both response and data and i got [object] [object], which i think is right

Comment: If it were right, the script would not complain, would it?

Comment: these are the result for data:Object {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array[5]}....and the results for buffered Object {type: "Feature", geometry: Object, properties: Object}.....are these what Turf expects?

Comment: Have a look at `turf.inside` docs. I have put the link in the above answer.

Comment: @ghybs...i have tried both and also not working,does it have to be polygon not circle??

Comment: when i tried turf.within i got this error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: You probably gave a single Feature as 2nd argument, whereas `turf.within` expects a Feature Collection. Please pay close attention to the docs.

Comment: @ghybs....can you help me on how to make the buffer feature collection not feature?

Comment: @NewatLeaflet would you be able to build a Plunker / JSFiddle / [Leaflet playground](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @ghybs...i edited a little my code and here is the link http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/pun/edit?html,js,output...check it...now it doesn't get error but the result array is empty :(

Comment: Please make a fully functional playground: add links to 3rd party libraries in the HTML section, call your main function in the JS section, make your AJAX calls to some dummy data, etc. For that dummy data, could be easier to use Plunker instead. Or no AJAX at all.